# Reading special characters from filename into variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, special-characters

I have thousands of files whose filenames contain the "caret" symbol, but when I try to assign them to a variable, I get weird results.  If the filename is `"01 ^ Driver's Seat.flac,"` for example, the command `echo %1` returns `"(path)\01 ^^ Driver's Seat.flac,"` with an extra caret, and processing halts.  How to I get the correct output?

Comment: There is a bug in your code in line 13 at the call statement! (Perhaps you should show code when you have problems with code)

Comment: [Buggy behaviour when using CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html): _If the CALL command contains a caret character within a quoted string `"test^ing"`, the carets will be doubled._ (`"test^^ing"`)

Comment: @JosefZ `CALL` always doubles the carets, even without quotes, but then  you normally can't see it (only with very special test cases)

Comment: If the file name is stored in a variable `VAR`, you could write `call :SUB "%%VAR%%"` instead of `call :SUB "%BAR%"`, which should fix it (in case you are actually using call, which I do not know as you do not show your code)...

Comment: If you are calling to a function then pass the variable name by reference to the function and expand it in the function. I showed you how to do this in one of your previous questions.

Comment: @jeb: Did you got another crystal ball? What model is this one? **`:)`**

Comment: Thanks, everybody, expecially Squashman and JosefZ.  Squashman, you did indeed answer me previously but I didn't understand that `CALL` always doubles the carets, until Josefz explained it here.  That suggests I _always_ have to plan for this behavior in the way you described.  Again, much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

Doubling of carets is a problem of the `CALL` command (see: [How the batch parser works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115)).

This can be avoided by using calling a function with variables by reference instead of variables by value.

> call :func "%variableName%"  -- by value
>   call :func variableName  -- by reference

```
call :func filename

...

:func
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "filename=!%1!"
echo filename: !filename!
```